# shortcut in jbutton tooltip not displaying in other themes apart from matalic

Tags: java, swing

We have requirement to display key board shortcuts in Jbutton tooltip, we have added action map and all required code for tooltip but shortcut is only displaying in Metalic look and feel, if we change application look and feel from metalic to system or any other look and feel, short cut is not displaying  in tool tip anymore.

Below is the example program, which shows 2 J buttons with shortcuts, the shortcuts is properly displaying with metalic look and feel, but if i use any other look and feel like system or Motif, shortcuts stopped displaying in J Button tool tip. To test the behaviour of below example in other look and feel please comment Metalic look and feel in example and enable System or Motif look and feel which is commented right now:

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel");
            // UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            // UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.motif.MotifLookAndFeel");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("KeyStroke Sample");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        final JButton buttonA = new JButton("a Button");
        buttonA.setMnemonic('a');
        frame.setVisible(true);
        buttonA.setToolTipText("a Button");
        final JButton buttonB = new JButton("another Button");
        buttonB.setMnemonic('b');
        frame.add(buttonA);
        frame.add(buttonB);
        buttonB.setToolTipText("another Button");
        Action action = new AbstractAction() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (e.getSource().equals(buttonA)) {
                    System.out.println("buttonA");
                }
                if (e.getSource().equals(buttonB)) {
                    System.out.println("buttonB");
                }
            }
        };
        buttonA.addActionListener(action);
        buttonB.addActionListener(action);

        // buttonA ("ALT+A");
        buttonA.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(
                KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, InputEvent.ALT_MASK),
                "left_button_pressed");
        buttonA.getActionMap().put("left_button_pressed", action);

        // buttonB ("CTRL+Shift+A");
        buttonB.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(
                KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK
                        | InputEvent.SHIFT_MASK), "right_button_pressed");
        buttonB.getActionMap().put("right_button_pressed", action);
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));

        frame.setSize(400, 200);

    }
}
```

Comment: Please post a short code example of a component with such a tooltip, action map etc. so we can see this for ourselves.

Comment: The example is added in question, please test the example with different look and feel, shortcuts only displays with Metalic look and feel but not with others

Comment: Thanks for the example. Note that `frame.setVisible(true)` should be called at the end of the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Displaying the accelerator string in the tooltip is something which is implemented only in Metal by default ("only" refers to all the other LAFs I tried). This behavior is defined in the `MetalToolTipUI` class, which is the class responsible for setting up and displaying the tooltips.

Fortunately the `UIManager` class allows you to set a `ToolTipUI`. You can use Metal's for any other LAF:

```
UIManager.getDefaults().put("ToolTipUI", "javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalToolTipUI");
```

For the LAFs that I checked, the tooltip's visual style (background color and font) adapted, but there might be cases in which the looks won't match. In this case, you might want to subclass `ToolTipUI` or one of its subclasses to suit your own needs.

Also, check that

```
UIManager.getDefaults().getBoolean("ToolTip.hideAccelerator");
```

returns `false` for a LAF. If it doesn't and the tooltip UI used respects this property, then the accelerator won't be displayed. You can set it to `true` in any case.

Comment: Thank you for the solution, after configuring ToolTipUI as Metal, the solution is working for me, I have also checked for other LAF and found that for other LAF ToolTipUI is set as BasicToolTipUI which does not have code to display accelerator string. So the only solution is to change the ToolTipUI class from BasicToolTipUI to MetalToolTipUI, changing property ToolTip.hideAccelerator will not help to display accelerator for other LAF. Thanks again for providing quick solution.

Comment: @Gaurav *"for other LAF ToolTipUI is set as BasicToolTipUI"*, *" changing property ToolTip.hideAccelerator will not help to display accelerator for other LAF*" LAFs can have their own implementation for a tooltip UI and it might respect the `hideAccelerator` property, so you can't make this generalization. This is also why I addressed it in my answer.

Comment: @Gaurav *"the only solution is to change the ToolTipUI class from BasicToolTipUI to MetalToolTipUI"* As I said, you can also create your own tooltip UI and implement the desired functionality.

Comment: this solution is working for all LAF apart from "com.jgoodies.looks.plastic.PlasticXPLookAndFeel", In this LAF, shortcut is not displayed even setting the ToolTipUI. Is there any other approach for this LAF?

Comment: @Gaurav It is not part of the Oracle API, I can't help you there. You will have to find the class responsible for rendering the tooltips. What does the `UIManager` return for the `ToolTipUI` property?

Comment: Thanks for support as always :), got the answer, for J Goodies we need to set additional property                 UIManager.put("ToolTip.hideAccelerator", false); Using this tooltip is also displaying in JGoodies as well. Thanks again..

Comment: @Gaurav This is *exactly* what I said in my answer and in my comment about the `hideAccelerator` property :)